# Input/Output rate for VLANs on Juniper devices

Tags: cisco, juniper, juniper-junos

Scenario:
I am passing traffic across multiple VLANs between a Cisco and a Juniper device.

On the Cisco device, when I do a `sh int ge-x/x/x.xx`, it gives the input/output rate on this VLAN (and gives rates on other VLANs, too). When I do the same on a Juniper device, the VLAN does not show the rate, only the parent interface shows the overall rate passing through the physical interface.

Question: On a Juniper device, how do I see the I/O rate per VLAN ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about layer 3 traffic for vlan interfaces that can be seen with 'show interfaces vlan.### extensive', if your trying to find it per vlan in total including layer 2 traffic that's not a capability of the device.

The only ways to find the layer 2 traffic rates would be to write a script gathering the interfaces that are in a specific vlan, parse the output for rates and then add them together or in a monitoring application create a view that has the all the interfaces in a vlan and show you the throughput of them, or with SFLOW you could have the device send you the stats and again parse the data somehow to add them together, but this again would mainly layer 3 data (it'll show you inter-vlan communication rates as well though at least).

Comment: So the all the rates shown are only layer 3 rates then? I tried confirming on Juniper documents if the rates are L2 or L3 but there was no information on this.

Comment: Yes, the VLAN interfaces are layer 3 interfaces. The only reason traffic would go to them is to either be routed or talk directly to the switch (MGMT, SNMP, Etc.). The physical ports are total throughput of incoming traffic regardless of OSI layer.